# How to handle multiple pages of the same site with the same outlinks

Tags: seo, backlinks

I am developing a back link tool for Chinese SEO (our web site URL is:

> `http://link.aizhan.com` just like ahrefs.com.

I encountered a problem which is how to handle multiple pages of the same site with the same out links.

For example:

Most pages of `bbs.chinaz.com` have the same out links such as:

```
 bbs.chinaz.com/Tea/thread-6293993-1-1.html
 bbs.chinaz.com/Tea/list-1.html
 bbs.chinaz.com/alimama/thread-6265032-1-1.html
 bbs.chinaz.com/alimama/thread-6265032-2-1.html?userid=-1&extParms=
 bbs.chinaz.com/Shuiba/list-1.html
 bbs.chinaz.com/FeedBack/thread-4456753-1-1.html
```

etc..

All of the pages have the same out links in the top of the page:

```
www.cnzz.com(anchor text:免费统计) 
www.313.com(建站大师) 
www.idc123.com（主机之家）
```

Suppose I store these outlinks into database. The SEO will find there are six backlinks from `bbs.chinaz.com` of `www.cnzz.com`. This is obviously no sense for the SEO.

Can you tell me how do you deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I use quite a few backlink toos, so I can tell you what I would like to see:

How many backlinks from a domain
How many pages from that domain are backlinking to me
How many of my pages are being linked to from that domain.

With that, details on the link text (or image based), nofollow status and the status of the landing page (is it missing) are also important.

Your database needs to be structured so it can manipulate the data in many ways. Entities could be domain, page and link where page and link have a many to many relationship.

Comment: yeah. It is very important how to design database model.  Seoer may search backlinks by domain and anchortext(Fuzzy Search by anchortext),so I need to use Full-text search Tool.But there is another problem which is  Full-text search Tool is not good for many to many  or one to many relationship